# Crud GET: React js axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, crud

I'm currently working on a personal project and I had an issue Im trying to getAll the cars data from my database using reactjs and axios so in the console I get all of them but in my page no, it was blank. knowing that working in the server side.

Here is the code :

**Component.jsx**

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
      this.onChangeModel = this.onChangeModel.bind(this);
      this.retrieveCars = this.retrieveCars.bind(this);
      this.saveCar = this.saveCar.bind(this);
      this.newCar = this.newCar.bind(this);
     
      

      this.state = {
        idCars: null,
        carName: "",
        carModel: "", 
        cars: [],
        submitted: false
      };

     
    }
   
componentDidMount() {
      this.retrieveCars();
    }
  
    retrieveCars() {
      DataService.getAll()
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          carsList: response.data
        });
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
       
    }

render() {
      const { cars } = this.state;
          return (      
            <div >
<h2>List of cars</h2>
 
                  
                    <ul className="list-group">
                    {
                    cars.map(data => (
                      <li>
                    {data.carName}
                      </li>
                    ))}
                      </ul>
                      <button
                    className="m-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                    onClick={this.retrieveCars}
                    >
                    display All
                    </button>
```

**DataService.js**

```
 getAll() {
      return http.get("/get");
    }
```

**http.js**

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  }
});
```

[image]

Please can someone guide me to fix this issue

Comment: How do you render data?

Comment: Typo.  You are using a state value called `cars` but never setting that value.  Instead you are setting a value called `carsList`.

Comment: @Viet Check the quest please I just update it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cars` instead `carsList` in `setState`

```
    this.setState({
      cars: response.data
    });
```